# removing a shower handle faucet stem

Tags: faucet

I have a phylrich two handle shower system.The hot water is leaking and cannot be completely turned off to eliminate the leak. I have unscrewed the stem and it feels free when unscrewing it but will not come out. I can see the threads and continue to turn it thinking it is not completely unscrewed but it turns easily and regardless of how many turns I continue to make, it will not let go. I have another stem to compare the length of the threads and I have unscrewed it sufficiently to assure clearing the threads but it is not letting go.

Comment: This is going to need pictures.

Comment: From my limited experience in these things, it seems like a gasket has cracked, causing the leak.  This same gasket/o-ring may be preventing you from pulling the stem out.  Sometimes a quick and firm (but not superhuman) pull can pop it out.  And sometimes this take a careful bit of prying to get out.  Once you get the stem out, it may only require replacing the gasket/o-ring to finish the fix.  Your extra stem may provide some insight on what you're looking to overcome, if this is the case.